# Continuity not supported to / from my iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I've just installed ios8 on Both my iPhone 5s and iPad 3 (model md329kn/a). However, I can't get continuity working.

Tried starting an e-Mail on the iPad, hitting the lockout button and picked up my iPhone. No icon in the lower left corner :/ Same the other Way from iPhone to iPad. They're both on the same wifi. Should also mention that I was able to call my iPhone from my gf's phone and answer it from the iPad.

Handoff enabled in iPhone settings menu in the general section under Siri but I thought the continuity is always on - only handoff needs to be enabled?

Also, no handoff menu is visible on my iPad where it is visible in the settings app on the other device.

Did I miss something or is the iPad not capable of handoff?

Comment: I read that the "Continuity" features will be enabled on a subsequent release. I noticed you still cannot pair your iPhone 5S and acceptable iPad models yet using bluetooth. Wondering if all this "Continuity" functionality comes out in a subsequent IOS 8 update?

Comment: The documentation is quite clear that Continuity should work between safari on two iOS devices. http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/continuity/ Do you have a reference to this not shipping with iOS 8.0 ?

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I have indeed read that.  I noted also that it says in grey-out "coming in October", which lead me to to the possibly conclusion that it will be an update to 8.0 in the near future.

Comment: It's my understanding that the iOS to Mac continuity will arrive in October when Yosemite ships.

Comment: But phone to pad should work, right?

Comment: is werking fine here!
Email, Safari On phone and iPad: lower left corner on lock screen and multitasking left swipe.

Comment: Which iPhone/iPad models are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoted from Apple.com

> Continuity features are available on iPhone 5 or later, iPad (4th generation), iPad Air, iPad mini, iPad mini with Retina display, and iPod touch (5th generation).

Comment: Apparently it only works on devices that support AirDrop.  While there's no reason why that shouldn't work with an iPad 3 (it has all of the necessary hardware, including Bluetooth Low Energy), Apple routinely excludes older devices from newer features to encourage upgrading to new hardware.

Comment: Correct.  I had Bluetooth turned off.  Turned it back on and it worked right away

Answer (score 0):

I read that continuity will not be fully functional until OSX is released sometime in late October.  Apple wants to wait until continuity is seamless between iMac, iPhone and iPad. Of course, there is always the chance that I don't know what I'm talking about...but there Ya go.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the SAME iCloud account on both the iPhone and iPad.  Turn off iMessage on both devices.  Wait 5 minutes.  Enable iMessage on both devices.  You should see "activating" under the option to turn on/off.  You should then get a pop-up on both devices that the iPad is using the iPhone.